# Error in the Django development server ("runserver")

Tags: python, django, pysqlite

I'm new to python and django and following the footsteps of "Django Book" I've django installed, including obtaining the following verification to import django in python:

```
>>>Import django
>>> django.VERSION 
(1, 3, 0, 'final', 0)
```

I also use startproject command to create a folder with the files 
__ init__.py, manage.py, settings.py and urls.py.

I also installed the executable pysqlite-2.6.0.win32-py2.6.

However, when trying to check the "Django development server" ("runserver")
following the steps in Chapter 2 of Django Book (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/), instead of finding the following message:

```
Validating models ...
0 errors found.
Django version 1.0, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I find this error:

[image]

There is also error when verifying the address http://localhost:8000
("This page can not be displayed ..." instead of "It worked"). The
Funny thing is that I've done it all before (it's the second time
I did the installation) and it had worked.

How do I procede to know what's wrong and move foward? Should I uninstall all Python 2.6 instalation and reinstall everything again? (already
I tried repairing and it did not work)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: do you have still have an older version of django still installed if so remove all and re-install the one you want or use virtual environments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is it you installed a newer version of django then install an older version? you should uninstall them all completely then try installing again.